# Javascript: Replace characters after _

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to do something which seems fairly basic, but can't seem to get it working.

I'm trying to strip the characters after the last instance of an underscore.

I have this string, for example:

www/images/10/20120412/28-696-b0b9815463e47c9371b02b7202788a75_tn.jpg

and I'm trying to strip out the 'tn.jpg' to produce:

www/images/10/20120412/28-696-b0b9815463e47c9371b02b7202788a75_

I tried doing .slice(0,-6) but that will only work for instances of _tn.jpg and not _med.jpg.

Ultimately, I'm going to be swapping in different sizes of images (_med.jpg, _full.jpg etc.) and it needs to be only after the last underscore (there might be underscores in the URL).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Zack

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can it like this:

```
var testURL = "dvuivnhuiv_ew";
var output = testURL.substring(0, testURL.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: he wants to include the _, so do +1

Answer (score 5):

```
var path = "www/images/10/20120412/28-696-b0b9815463e47c9371b02b7202788a75_tn.jpg";
var index = path.lastIndexOf('_');
path = path.substring(0, index+1);
alert(path);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry missed the part where there could be more _'s in the beginning

Comment: change it to lastIndexOf. You were a bit faster :(

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = "www/images/10/20120412/28-696-b0b9815463e47c9371b02b7202788a75_tn.jpg";
var result = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('_')+1);
alert(result);
```

[**​Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/znwBQ/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "www/images/10/20120412/28-696-b0b9815463e47c9371b02b7202788a75_tn.jpg";
var result = url.substring( 0,url.indexOf('_')+1);
alert(result);
//or you can type only after _
var url = "www/images/10/20120412/28-696-b0b9815463e47c9371b02b7202788a75_tn.jpg";
var result = url.substring( url.indexOf('_'));
alert(result);
// (substring) is mean how much you want display chracter and where like from 0 to 63


// (indexOf) is mean number chracter on line


// note: if u have two _ i think will get some problme
```